# How to grep repeated strings on a single line?

Tags: grep

I have this a file.txt with one line, whose content is

```
/app/jdk/java/bin/java -server -Xms3g -Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=O2pPod8_mapp_msrv1_1 -Djava.security.policy=/app/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=/app/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/O2pPod8_domain/servers/O2pPod8_mapp_msrv1_1/data/nodemanager/boot.properties -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true -Dweblogic.nmservice.RotationEnabled=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=false -Dweblogic.ReverseDNSAllowed=false -Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:NewSize=1300m -XX:MaxNewSize=1300m -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
```

and when I do

```
cat file.txt | grep -io "Xms.*" | awk '{FS" ";  print $1} ' | cut -d  "s" -f2
```

output:

```
3g
```

why is grep not reading the second occurrence, i.e. I expect 3g and 8192m.
Infact, how do I print only 8192m in this case?

Comment: What are you hoping that `FS" "` will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here but if you want the endings of all space-separated strings starting with `-Xms`, using bare awk is:

```
$ awk -v RS=" " '/^-Xms/{print substr($0,5)}' file
3g
8192m
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v RS=" " '       # space separated records
/^-Xms/ {               # strings starting with -Xms
    print substr($0,5)  # print starting from 5th position
}' file
```

If you wanted something else (word *repeated* in the title puzzles me a bit), please update the question with more detailed requirements.

**Edit**: I just noticed *how do I print only 8192m in this case* (that's the *repeated* maybe). Let's add a counter `c` and not print the first instance:

```
$ awk -v RS=" " '/^-Xms/&&++c>1{print substr($0,5)}' file
8192m
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex just says "find Xms followed by anything repeated 0 to n times". That returns the rest of the row from Xms onward.

What you actually want is something like "find Xms followed by anything until there's a whitespace repeated 0 to n times".

```
grep -io "Xms[^ ]*" file.txt | awk '{FS" ";  print $1} ' | cut -d  "s" -f2
```

In `[^ ]` the `^` means "not"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep -io "Xms[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]"` instead of `grep -io "Xms.*"` to match a sequence of digits followed by a single character instead the entire line within a single group:

```
cat file.txt | grep -io "Xms[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]" | awk '{FS" ";  print $1} ' | cut -d  "s" -f2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `.*` in your regexp is matching the rest of the line, you need `[^ ]*` instead. Look:

```
$ grep -o 'Xms.*' file
Xms3g -Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=O2pPod8_mapp_msrv1_1 -Djava.security.policy=/app/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=/app/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/O2pPod8_domain/servers/O2pPod8_mapp_msrv1_1/data/nodemanager/boot.properties -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true -Dweblogic.nmservice.RotationEnabled=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=false -Dweblogic.ReverseDNSAllowed=false -Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:NewSize=1300m -XX:MaxNewSize=1300m -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled

$ grep -o 'Xms[^ ]*' file
Xms3g
Xms8192m

$ grep -o 'Xms[^ ]*' file | cut -d's' -f2
3g
8192m

$ grep -o 'Xms[^ ]*' file | cut -d's' -f2 | tail -1
8192m
```

or more concisely:

```
$ sed 's/.*Xms\([^ ]*\).*/\1/' file
8192m
```

Answer (score 0):

The `positive lookbehind` of PCRE (the form: `(?<=RE1)RE2`) can resolve the problem easily:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=Xms)\S+' file.txt
3g
8192m
```

Explains:

- `-o`: show only the part of a line matching PATTERN.
- `-P`: PATTERN is a Perl regular expression.
- `(?<=Xms)\S+`: matches all continuous `non-whitespace` strings which are just following the string `Xms`.